# Java REST split part of token body, and return it

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have a Java token, that is used for authentication between the client and the server, and as of now I get it in this format:

```
bearer{token}
```

now I want to crop out bearer so I only have the value of the token:

so far i have made this method:

```
    public static String cropToken(String token){
    token = token.replace("bearer{", "");
    token = token.replace("}", "");
    return token;
}
```

then i assign the new token back to the original refrence in the resource:

```
    public Response create(@HeaderParam("Authorization")String token, String content) throws IOException, AuthenticationException
    {
    TokenAuthenticator authenticator = new TokenAuthenticator(() -> new 
JpaUserRepository(JpaConnection.create()));
    token =TokenSplitter.cropToken(token);
    AuthenticationContext  authenticationContext = 
authenticator.authenticate(token);
```

is this a best practice or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Well, for one, that code doesn't work, since you never assign return value from `replace` to anything. Remember, `String` is immutable, so code should be `token = token.replace("}", "")`

Comment: Andreas' point regarding the String is spot on.  Also, you should consider following the standard for the `Authorization` header, which is `Authorization: <type> <value>`.  If using the header properly, you could then get the token via a simple `token.split(" ")[1]`

Comment: but the token.split(" "),[1] would still contain the last curly bracket right? If i only want the pure data of the token?

Comment: If you follow the recommended format, there won't be any curly braces in the first place. E.g. `Authorization: Basic YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l`.
See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization